# Having error in predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat") RuntimeError:

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, dlib

I'm keep running with error in line 8.

> `predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat") RuntimeError: Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.da`

I downloaded the files I tried to add the files to working directory but PyCharm doesn't let me drag and drop anything.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import dlib

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

def midpoint(p1 ,p2):
    return int((p1.x + p2.x)/2), int((p1.y + p2.y)/2)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = detector(gray)
    for face in faces:
        #x, y = face.left(), face.top()
        #x1, y1 = face.right(), face.bottom()
        #cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        landmarks = predictor(gray, face)
        left_point = (landmarks.part(36).x, landmarks.part(36).y)
        right_point = (landmarks.part(39).x, landmarks.part(39).y)
        center_top = midpoint(landmarks.part(37), landmarks.part(38))
        center_bottom = midpoint(landmarks.part(41), landmarks.part(40))

        hor_line = cv2.line(frame, left_point, right_point, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        ver_line = cv2.line(frame, center_top, center_bottom, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: To users seeing this, I'm not really sure what tags I should have added but since I was editing I added what made sense until an SME takes a look and makes a better decision.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem. I went in my Mac open pycharm install dlib and at first I had the same problem. the type in google shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat. search different option the best source: https://github.com/davisking/dlib-models/blob/master/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2 download the file and I dropped the file in sam

Comment: Hi! I followed the steps and unzipped the donwloaded file and placed in the same folder of my python project. But, It still gives me the same error:( Any help how can I resolve this issue? Thanks!