# RuntimeError: Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting the an error after trying to run the following code in my OpenCV file in Python:

```
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
```

I have downloaded the **shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat** by following this stackOverflow answer:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66202687/13218692
```

Any suggestions on how can I resolve this issue? Appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by specifying the complete path to the file :- **shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat** in a separate variable. Here is the code for your reference:

```
path = '/Users/name/OpenCV_Python/EyeGazeDetection/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat'

predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(path)
```

**Note**:- Make sure to include the **.dat file** in the same folder where your python project is located.